# Is there any database with versioning (column based) built in?

Tags: nosql, data-versioning

I'm wondering if there is a database (SQL or NOSQL) which provides versioning for for the records ( if the column/field/property is enabled for versioning). I'm developing an authentication software and I need to provide a log /"history" for a number of properties so I'm wondering if there is a built-in feature or I need to reinvent the wheel one more time.

Comment: DB2 10.5 have support for both business time and system time if that is what you mean by versioning

Comment: Here's a link to an article on the subject: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-1204db2temporaldata/

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server has Change Data Capture in it's Enterprise edition.

From msdn [link to information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/cc645937(v=sql.120).aspx):

> Change data capture records insert, update, and delete activity that
>   is applied to a SQL Server table. This makes the details of the
>   changes available in an easily consumed relational format. Column
>   information and the metadata that is required to apply the changes to
>   a target environment is captured for the modified rows and stored in
>   change tables that mirror the column structure of the tracked source
>   tables. Table-valued functions are provided to allow systematic access
>   to the change data by consumers.